# Filtro complexo com multiplicações no model do Django

Tags: django, django-2.0

Estou com uma dúvida que tenho desde o início de um projeto que estou desenvolvendo e ainda não encontrei uma resposta...

Tenho 2 models no meu projeto em Django:

```
class Turma(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class Pessoa(models.Model):
    turma = models.ForeignKey(Turma, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    multiplicador = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2)
```

Supondo que eu tenha uma turma com 20 pessoas nela, se eu quisesse a soma de todos os multiplicadores, seria algo assim:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
turma = Turma.objects.get(pk = 1)
soma = turma.pessoa_set.aggregate(soma = Sum('multiplicador'))['soma']
```

Mas e se eu quiser a multiplicação de todos os multiplicadores? Existe uma forma de conseguir isso sem ter que apelar para um for com prefetch_related?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma função aggregate no seu banco de dados primeiro como especificado nessa [reposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623282/multiplynum-aggregate-function-in-postgresql)

```sql
CREATE AGGREGATE MUL(bigint) ( SFUNC = int8mul, STYPE=bigint );
```

Depois você pode criar uma função [Aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#creating-your-own-aggregate-functions) que usará a função que você acabou de criar.

```py
from django.db.models import Aggregate, IntegerField

class Multiplication(Aggregate):
    function = 'MUL'
    template = '%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(expressions)s)'

    def __init__(self, expression, distinct=False, **extra):
        super().__init__(
            expression,
            distinct='DISTINCT ' if distinct else '',
            output_field=IntegerField(),
            **extra
    )
```

Dessa forma você poderá chamar a função em aggregate como você faria na soma

```py
soma = turma.pessoa_set.aggregate(soma = Sum('multiplicador'))['soma']
mult = turma.pessoa_set.aggregate(mult = Multiplication('multiplicador'))['mult']
```

Note que esta função depende do tamanho do [BigInt](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-integer/) do postgres (se você estiver usando-o). Ainda mais se tratando de uma mutiplicação em que o número cresce rapidamente.